# Runtime error when checking colorScheme environment variable in unit tests?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

After updating to Xcode 14.1, when unit testing the following code:

```
struct MyView<T: ItemProtocol>: View
{
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var result: T
    
    var body: some View
    {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
            Text(result.displayName)
                .font(.inter(size: 16, weight: .regular, italic: false))
                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .navigationBarTint : .darkBlue)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        }
    }
}
```

`.foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .navigationBarTint : .darkBlue)` gives me the following runtime error:

`Accessing Environment<ColorScheme>'s value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update.`

1. This was not an issue before the update
2. When running the app normally and testing the code between dark/light mode, there are no runtime errors and it works correctly
3. If I change this code to appease the compiler to not show the error, the runtime error just pops up somewhere else in the code with the same colorScheme check

Am I doing something wrong in my code, unit tests setup or is this a bug with Xcode 14.1?

Comment: Why are you accessing a `View` from unit tests? When running unit tests, the UI of an app is not initialised properly, that's why the system doesn't inject the `colorScheme` environment variable to the app's view hierarchy. You shouldn't be unit testing views. If you want to test UI, use UI tests or snapshot tests. Unit tests are for testing logic, not UI.

Comment: I am using `ViewInspector` to test SwiftUI views in isolation to verify elements depending on the state (which I believe  is pretty normal from my research) - I feel UI tests would overkill for small short tests like this.